# Power Query - How to run multiple SQL queries against a single SQL query result?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a SQL server query that has 7 joins and pulls over 50 columns. I run this in SSMS, query results are stored in a local temp table, and then there are a dozen or so SELECT statements within the query that run based off the temp table. I have no control over the data itself, and only have read access to the tables. So basically:

```
SELECT *
INTO #myTempTable
FROM myTableAnd7Joins

SELECT <stuff>
FROM #myTempTable

SELECT <different stuff>
FROM #myTempTable

<like 10 more SELECT statements>
```

The temp table can easily be 500,000 rows and can take 5-10 minutes to return.

I run this query once, where it creates the single temp table and then multiple sets of results are returned. I then copy and paste each set of results to various tabs in an Excel file, and the rest of the Excel file is already populated with formulas and such which read the data from those tabs. I want to get rid of having to copy and paste from SSMS to Excel and do everything in Excel instead. I also want to use parameterized queries, so I can change some of the query variables on the fly. The parameters are stored in a range on a tab named 'Parameters'.

I currently have an Excel workbook saved that has the dozen individual Power Query queries, but each one has to do that initial query into #myTempTable first before performing it's specific query.

Each of my current dozen queries look like this:

```
LET
    myParamTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tParams"]}[Content],
    fieldList = myParamTable[#"Parameter"],
    valueList = myParamTable[Value],
    param1 = valueList{List.PositionOf(fieldList, "First Parameter")},
    param2 = valueList{List.PositionOf(fieldList, "Second Parameter")},
    param3 = valueList{List.PositionOf(fieldList, "Third Parameter")},

    Source = Sql.Database("mySqlServer", "DatabaseName"), 

    GoQuery = Value.NativeQuery(Source,
    "
    DECLARE
        @ <a bunch of different variables>
    BEGIN
        SET <a bunch of different variables>
    END

    SELECT <50 different columns from all the tables>
    INTO #myTempTable
    FROM myTable t1
    JOIN otherTable t2 on t1.thing = t2.thing
    JOIN <6 or 7 other tables to t1>

    SELECT <complex stuff that's more than just a filter or two>
    FROM #myTempTable
    WHERE <something> = p1

    DROP TABLE #myTempTable",
    [p1 = param1,
     p2 = param2,
     p3 = param3])

IN
    GoQuery
```

Is it possible to create #myTempTable just once, and then have the dozen other queries use that as the source, instead of having to create #myTempTable each time? I tried to put #myTempTable into a table and then get the data From Table/Range but don't see how I can replicate my SQL as suggested in a previous question of mine ([Power Query - Can a range be queried using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68596210/power-query-can-a-range-be-queried-using-sql))